# Elastic Search list of unique values of a field from Match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search to get a list of all products of a kind (say camera), but I want to dynamically populate the list of manufacturers from the result I got from the match query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product_type" : "CAMERA"
    }
  }
}
```

gives me a list of such items (after removing irrelevant data)

```
{
    "_score": 11.234668,
    "_source": {
        "product_type": "CAMERA",
        "mfg_name": "SONY"
    }
}
```

I can't aggregate all the `mfg_name` from the document as it would also contain manufacturers of other products as well. What I would like to do, get all the `mfg_name` for the product type I queried.

Is this natively supported by elastic search? Can I chain my queries such that output of `match` query is operated on by `aggs` query? Or do I have to write a service to go through the items one by one and get the list?

Edit: I use this to get the aggregate since Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "manufacturer" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "mfg_name.keyword",  "size" : 500 }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the query results. Just need to write all in the same query.

[Aggregation over the query results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html)

[Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

You should index the mfg_name field as a non analyzed string in order to be able to do aggregations on that field. Otherwise you will get weird results like an aggregation for SON an another for ONY for instance.

Responding here to be able to paste code.

Update the index

```
PUT my_index {  "mappings": {
    "doc": { 
      "properties": { 
        "mfg_name":    { "type": "text"  }, 
        "mfg_name_na":     { "type": "text" , index: "not_analyzed" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm copying the mfg_name to a non analyzed field so you can do full text search over the original one, and then do aggregations over the non analyzed one.

Then reindex and you can query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product_type": "CAMERA"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "producers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mfg_name_na"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should receive a response containing a bucket aggregation with te desired data.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how it would be used in my case?

Comment: It works, can you tell me why it is not fetching `mfg_name` from the document again and performing aggregation over it? Why it is performing aggregate over query instead of the document directly? Also, can you tell me if using `"field": "mfg_name.keyword"` is okay?

Comment: I don't catch you. You want to get the list of camera producers, so you have to aggregate over the filtered results. If you aggregate over the index, you will get the whole producers lists for any product. Regarding to the second question, I haven't used that. When I have to make an aggregation over a string field I always use this approach. Also depending on which version are you using you could define the field as keyword instead of text with non analyzed.